# AllowGroups in the /etc/ssh/sshd_config file

Tags: sed, regular-expression

The following `sed` command adds `my_unix_admins` to the end of the lines starting with the word `AllowGroups`.

```
/bin/sed -i '/^AllowGroups / s/$/ my_unix_admins/' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

I want to only add  `my_unix_admins` if does not already exist in the line (in order to not having the entry duplicated).

By other words, check it and only add it if it does not exist in that line.

How do I do that ?

Comment: It's not clear what is the requirement. Can you provide an example with some input and output data?

Comment: Inside /etc/ssh/sshd_config file there is a line starting with the word AllowGroups
I want to add the word my_unix_admins to (the end of) line starting with the word AllowGroups
only if the word my_unix_admins does not exist in the line starting with the word AllowGroups
Otherwise, I will have duplicate entry

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it would be to first match the AllowGroups line, then if that line does not contain "my_unix_admins", do the end-of-line replacement that you already had:

```
sed '/^AllowGroups/ { /my_unix_admins/ !s/$/ my_unix_admins/; }' /etc/ssh/sshd_config > /etc/ssh/sshd_config.new
```

This uses [braces](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/sed-commands-list.html#sed-commands-list) to group the "my_unix_admins" search inside the AllowGroups match. The other important feature here is the [`!` inversion](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Addresses-overview.html#Addresses-overview) that performs the s// replacement function *only* on lines that do *not* match the previous range (here, the /my_unix_admins/ pattern search).

I've linked to the GNU sed online manual on the assumption that you're using GNU sed, but the braces and the inversion feature are both [specified by POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html) so you could also consult your local man page. The only non-POSIX feature of your original command was the `-i` option, which GNU sed supports.

The only corner case I can imagine is if you had a group named "astronomy_unix_admins" or "my_unix_admins_on_mars" in the AllowGroups line; then the simple /my_unix_admins/ pattern match would falsely match. To avoid potential false matches, you could use GNU sed and enable extended regular expressions (for the `|` alternation) with the `-E` option and use:

```
sed -E '/^AllowGroups/ { / my_unix_admins( |$)/ !s/$/ my_unix_admins/; }' < /etc/ssh/sshd_config > /etc/ssh/sshd_config.new
```

The two changes are:

- require a leading space before the group name -- which will be true if it's the first group in the list or anywhere else in the list.
- require either a trailing space (which will prevent false matches in the middle of the line) or the end-of-line marker (which allows the group to be the last one in the line).